# Call another datatable except default datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined` .

The problem is, i have default table.

```
$("#mainFolder").dataTable();
```

In my project, the Default Table is much of Data.

---

In this case, i want adding New table.

i use `$(".tab-content table").dataTable();` for making the New table have 'DataTable View' .

but, it's will display the default table without the 'DataTable View' when first displaying the page.

[image]

---

When im using `$("#mainFolder").dataTable();` and  i calling `dataTable()` on all tables in tab-content container after the for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultTable.length; i++) {
    var items = resultTable[i];
    $(".tab-content").append(items.table);
}

$(".tab-content table").dataTable();
```

I will get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined .`

> **How to both them without get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined .` ?**

[<kbd>JSFiddle Demo 1</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gtwnueq8/9/)

[<kbd>JSFiddle Demo 2</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gtwnueq8/10/)

Comment: By, "In my project, the Default Table is much of Data.", do you mean that the data table is too big?  That it contains so much data that it is unable to function?  Is it that you have too much data to view at once?

Comment: So you don't argue, because I get a lot of tables.

And I differentiate the default table with other tables but in 1 parent div.

Comment: In order for you to understand if in my project, the default table is not empty. because maybe you will also assume "Why the default table with other tables do not use 1 datatable command because the same using empty table?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is discussed here:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32575/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-dt-cellindex-of-undefined

> In a dataTable that has 0 entries, but has a column with no title or a
>   title of just ( ). (For example a column for action buttons that has
>   no title), this causes a JS error like in original report.
>
> This issue is immediately resolved once the amount of rows in table is
>   greater than 0.

Your first header column is empty, `<th></th>`.  Try putting in a non-breaking space `<th>&nbsp;</th>` or a single character, like `<th>*</th>`, and see if that fixes it.

Also, the very first time it runs, you are not calling .dataTable on the table.  You try to load `localStorage` with this line:

```
var resultTable = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tableList"));
```

This results in `null`, so the `else` is executed:

```
} else {
  let inititalTable = [];
  inititalTable.push({
    table: $('div.tab-content').html()
  });
  localStorage.setItem("tableList", JSON.stringify(inititalTable));
}
```

This adds your table html to `localStorage`.  But it does not call .dataTable on the table.

To this `else` code you could add `$(".tab-content table").dataTable();`.  Or you could move that out of the if altogether, and place it at the bottom:

```
var resultTable = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tableList"));
if (resultTable != null) {
  //get the nav reference in DOM
  let tableContent = $(".tab-content");

  //clear the html contents
  tableContent.html('');

  for (var i = 0; i < resultTable.length; i++) {
    var items = resultTable[i];
    $(".tab-content").append(items.table);
  }
 // Moved to end $(".tab-content table").dataTable();

} else {
  let inititalTable = [];
  inititalTable.push({
    table: $('div.tab-content').html()
  });
  localStorage.setItem("tableList", JSON.stringify(inititalTable));
}

  $(".tab-content table").dataTable();
```

Comment: Did you see when page reloaded? the new table not display 'datatable view'.

Comment: It does for me.  Which brings us to another issue: wrap your initialisation code with $(document).ready(function(){ [init code here]});  See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ac8mjehn/2/

Comment: Please try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ac8mjehn/17/  You should clear your local storage as I added another class ("dynamicTable") to the table and any that are stored locally won't have that class.

Comment: it's brilliant. I just understood something like this. new knowledge for me. update your answer. thankyou.